# Можно ли посмотреть рейтинг пользователей по влиянию?

Tags: обсуждение, профиль-участника, статистика

Интересно узнать, как коррелирует репутация и количество людей, затронутых человеком. Часто замечаю пользователей с большей репутацией, чем у меня, но у которых в профиле на порядок меньше число людей, которых он затронул. Есть ли такой рейтинг по влиянию?

Ещё интересны мысли по поводу того, как такая ситуация может получаться, что при одной репутации существенно отличается влияние. Я часто, как и многие, вместо развёрнутого ответа на вопрос оставляю просто комментарий. Влияют ли комментарии на влияние?

Сейчас посмотрел подробнее и понял, что, видимо, это я слишком медленно набираю репутацию. Я просто дольше зарегистрирован по сравнению с пользователями, которых я имел в виду.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Конкретно по влиянию можно накидать [простенький запрос на stackexchange](https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/1206157), чтоб получить топ:

[image: топ по влиянию]

> Ещё интересны мысли по поводу того, как такая ситуация может получаться, что при одной репутации существенно отличается влияние. Я часто, как и многие, вместо развёрнутого ответа на вопрос оставляю просто комментарий. Влияют ли комментарии на влияние?

Про влияние можно [тут](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/244534/260198) почитать. Влияние - это, по сути, сумма просмотров ваших сообщений (не всех, а тех, что критериям удовлетворяют; можно по ссылке почитать). Так что, в ТОПе по влияние люди, у которых много вопросов с большим число просмотров, типа таких:

- [Что такое NullReferenceException, и как мне исправить код](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/413041/15479)?
- [Вычисления на числах с плавающей точкой не работают](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/417453/15479).
- [Как сравнивать строки в Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/417405/15479)?
- И т.п.

Comment: Был бы признателен, если бы вы набросали запрос, чтоб еще пару столбцов было - срок на сайте, количество вопросов и количество ответов. Есть пара мыслей, хотелось их проверить, а с sql я работал чисто эпизодически + совершенно не знаю структуры таблиц сайта. Можно просто ссылку на соответствующий запрос... Заранее спасибо :)

Comment: @Harry добавил. Запрос всё [тот же](https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/1206157).

Comment: На правах шутки :) Выдвинул для себя гипотезу, что "влияние" зависит от количества вопросов/ответов и срока, причем от срока - нелинейно: активность на ruSO падает, он становится все больше спасением для лентяев, которые смотрят только в ответ на свой вопрос... Корреляция влияния с *взятым навскидку* (вопросы+ответы)*дни^2 вышла 0.878... Гипотеза почти подтвердилась :)

Comment: Кстати, если будет время и вдохновение... Заинтересовала гистограмма средней оценки вопроса/ответа со временем. Да, я понимаю, что старые ответы и сейчас могут плюсовать, так что они будут иметь рейтинг выше... но насколько выше?